# What is wrong with my attempt to unhide element when loaded or scroll into them?

Tags: jquery, scroll

**My objective:**

On a page with multiple `div.inView` that are defaulted to be hidden. I want them to animate and unhide when any portion of the div is within viewport, be it loaded or scrolled into them.

**My codes:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Check if page has .inView
    if ( $('.inView')[0] ) {

        // Get viewport
        var wt = $(window).scrollTop();
        var wb = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();

        // If true, unhide by removing class
        function checkVis(e) {
            console.log('> > checking');

            var et = e.offset().top;
            var eb = e.offset().top + e.outerHeight();

            // Check if top or bottom are within viewport, or if top and bottom are bigger than viewport
            if ( ( (wt < et) &&
                   (wb > et) ) ||
                 ( (wt < eb) &&
                   (wb > eb) ) ||
                 ( (wt < et) &&
                   (wb > eb) ) ) {
                console.log('> > > removing');
                e.removeClass('preanimated');
            }
        }

        // Initial check to unhide any .inView that are already in viewport
        $('.preanimated').each(function() {
            console.log('each');
            checkVis( $(this) );
        });

        // Check again if scrolling causes any .inView to pass the test
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            console.log('> scrolling');

            $('.preanimated').each(function() {
                console.log('each again');
                checkVis( $(this) );
            });
        });

    }

});
```

**The results:**

Only the initial run of the `checkVis()` works. Even though the later `.scroll` works, and will go into `checkVis()`, it does not trigger `console.log('> > > removing');` to remove the class again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put wt and wb inside the checkVis function. Then the calculation should work as intended